# "Not a function" error in d3 V4 when trying to use projection.center() on AlbersUSA

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm going off the current D3 documentation but it seems my version 4 of D3 isn't taking the projection.center([lon, lat]) function when I set the projection.

I'm trying this:

```
var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa().center([-71.382439, 42.407211]);
```

And keep getting this error:

```
d3.geoAlbersUsa(...).center is not a function
```

Is there a new syntax or something I'm missing?

Comment: The AlbersUsa projection is a special case: from the (earlier v3) docs: "The Albers USA projection does not support rotation or centering." This is due to its composite nature. If you want to center and look at one part try a plain Albers and rotate with `.rotate(-lon,-lat)` (as opposed to center - as the default rotation of the albers will affect the centering coordinates). If looking at one part of the US the two projections are identical. Another option is fitSize() or fitExtent for either albersUsa or a plain albers *if* you have a non point feature you want to zoom to.

Comment: I just tried var projection = d3.geoAlbers.rotate([-71.382439, 42.407211]); and it's just blank with no errors now ...

Comment: You need to rotate -lon -lat, if your point is in the US that would be 71,-42. Rotation moves the globe under you hence the negatives. This is why it's blank: you're looking at the opposite side of the globe.